# How to decode android app bundle .pb files

Tags: android, apk, protocol-buffers, android-app-bundle

I've found that to decode files like manifest is as simple as:
protoc --decode=aapt.pb.XmlNode Resources.proto < AndroidManifest.xml > output.txt

What im looking for is what would be proto message to decode other files, specifically BundleConfig.pb
Cant manage to find out how to decode this file.

Comment: These resources may help you answer your own question: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/app-bundle-format https://github.com/google/bundletool/blob/master/src/main/proto/config.proto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found how in case anyone needs it.

protoc --decode=aapt.pb.ResourceTable Resources.proto < Bundleconfig.pb > output.txt